# Why does this jQuery not insert the value of the HTML <li> into the <input>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="text" class="dropInput">
<ul class="inputDrop">
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Goodbye</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" class="dropInput">
<ul class="inputDrop">
<li>Hola</li>
<li>Adios</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and I have this jQuery:

```
$('.inputDrop li').live('click', function(){

currentOption  = $(this).html();

$(this).prev('.dropInput').val(currentOption);

});
```

It is supposed to make it so that when you click on one of the `<li>`s it's value is inserted in the `<input>` just before the list, but it is not doing this. Any reason why this is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this)` will refer to the `li` element, not the parent `ul`.

Try this instead...

```
$('.inputDrop li').live('click', function(){

   var currentOption = $(this).html();

   $(this).closest('ul').prev('.dropInput').val(currentOption);

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/GBvq5/).

It is also a good idea to declare variables with `var`, otherwise the become properties of the global object (`window` in a browser environment).

Comment: oh yeah, I usually do, that was just a mistake, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method:

```js
$('.inputDrop li').live('click', function() {
    var li = $(this);
    var currentOption = li.html();
    li.parent().prev('.dropInput').val(currentOption);
});
```